# NiFi ListenHTTP processor: how to specify "allow post"?

Tags: apache-nifi

Just getting started with nifi.
Have an http processor of type "ListenHTTP" listening no port 9090
Need to allow http POST on http://localhost:9090/ end-point
I was unable to locate any "acceptable http verbs" settings within the Web UI for this processor, so my guess is - it needs to be specified in some sort of config file.
My question is: what file would that be, and what is the actual syntax to specify this?
I have seen some xml templates on line, but I'm not sure where to put one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, if no alternative base name is specified, the **ListenHTTP** processor's endpoint is available at:

```
http://{hostname}:{port}/contentListener
```

Accordingly, your request should, for default settings, be:

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" localhost:9090/contentListener
```

The full documentation on the processor is available at [ListenHTTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListenHTTP/index.html) or if that link breaks, via the [Nifi Documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/) page.

Alternatively, if you were looking to restrict your endpoint to specific verbs consider the combination of [HandleHttpRequest](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpRequest/index.html) and [HandleHttpResponse](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpResponse/index.html)

Comment: Apache Nifi v 1.0.0
POST returns:
HTTP ERROR: 405
HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Comment: i receive the error `method is not supported` when url contains `/` at the end...

Answer (score 1):

I believe by default it will accept all verbs. I configured ListenHttp on port 9090 with an empty "Base Path" property, and was able to use curl to POST data to it successfully. What kind of issues are you having?

Comment: curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://localhost:9090/
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 405 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 405</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /. Reason:
<pre>    HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</pre></p>
<hr /><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.9.v20160517</a><hr/>
</body>
</html>

Comment: What version of NiFi are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The **ListenHTTP** processor...

> ... starts an HTTP Server and listens on a given base path to transform
>   incoming requests into FlowFiles. The default URI of the Service will
>   be http://{hostname}:{port}/contentListener. Only HEAD and POST
>   requests are supported. GET, PUT, and DELETE will result in an error
>   and the HTTP response status code 405.
>
> -- [Nifi Documentation, ListenHTTP 1.6.0](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListenHTTP/index.html)

I have been able to POST to Nifi using PowerShell with `Invoke-WebRequest`, but needed to specify `-ContentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. This content type is set implicitly in the `curl` command in the answer from @apiri.

The example below works, and as an added bonus shows how you might include a header that will set an attribute on the resulting flowfile. Remember that you need to set the optional **HTTP Headers to receive as Attributes (Regex)** property in the processor configuration.

```
[PS] $HttpPost = @{
    Uri = "http://{hostname}:{port}/contentListener"
    Method = "POST"
    ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Headers = @{MyAttribute = "SomeValue"}
}

[PS] $Body = Get-Content <some_file> -Raw

[PS] Invoke-WebRequest @HttpPOST -Body:$Body

VERBOSE: POST http://{hostname}:{port}/contentListener with -1-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 0-byte response of content type text/plain

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
```